# How to find what random string the bot will choose from an array [Discord.js]

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So when a user types something like "!biscuit" the bot will choose a random string from the array (and the array has like "you can eat biscuits" and "you cant eat biscuits") and I want if the bot sends a message like "you can eat biscuits" to add a specific role to that user. I've done everything I just dont know how to check what the bot chose so I can add the role to the user.

Comment: `if (element === 'you can eat biscuits')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a simple array containing every possible outcome (e.g. `const responses = ["you can eat biscuits", "you cant eat biscuits"]`.

Then, use the `Math.random()` function to get a random number between 0 and <1.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(responses.length)) 
// this will return a number between 0 and the length of 'responses'
```

"The `Math.floor()` function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number"
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

```
let randomMessage = responses[randomNumber]; 
// this gives you a random element from the "responses" array.
```

To add a role to the member who sent the message, you could use the following code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);
    member.roles.add('role-id');
});
```

Really useful links that you should check out:

https://discordjs.guide/

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

EDIT: A simple way to decide if you want to add a role or not, you could try to change the response array, adding another element on every response, with the first element containing the message, then second being a boolean, which will be used as a condition, with `true` being eligible to add role and `false` for not eligible.

`const responses = [["you can eat biscuits", true], ["you cant eat biscuits", false]]`.

`randomMessage` should look like this now: `let randomMessage = responses[randomNumber][0];`

The final code should look like this now:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);
  const responses = [["you can eat biscuits", true], ["you cant eat biscuits", false]];
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(responses.length));
  let randomMessage = responses[randomNumber][0];
  message.channel.send(randomMessage);
    if(responses[randomNumber][1]) {
     member.roles.add('role-id');
    };
});
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it out right after I posted it lol, but thank you